# laravel model and controller best practice

Tags: laravel, postgresql, model, controller

I'm learning to use laravel 8.~ with DB PostgreSQL 12.~ . I want to ask if my approach to fetch data from DB via model method as in the code snippet below is effective or not? Thank you.

This is a model code snippet.

```
class Product extends Model{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'price'
    ];

    static function getAllData(){
       return Product::get();
    }
 }
```

This is a controller code snippet.

```
use App\Models\Product;

class HomeController extends Controller{
    public function getHomePage(){
        return view('home', ['productData' => Product::getAllData()]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... why you want to call one function inside another function ? if you can directly do this `return view('home', ['productData' => Product::all()]);`

Comment: Learn and stick with practices described on [this](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices) page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it. Product extends from core model has a method get all data.

```
use App\Models\Product;

class HomeController extends Controller{
    public function getHomePage(){
        return view('home', ['productData' => Product::all()]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $fillable = ['name','price'] you should use $guarded = [], because in case if you add another column in your Product table you don't have to change your model too.